# How to set tags for Secret in Azure Key Vault using C#

Tags: c#, azure-keyvault

I need to create new secret in Azure KeyVault, and set its tags.

When I check documentation for C# library (Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets), https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.security.keyvault.secrets.secretproperties.tags?view=azure-dotnet - `Tags` property is read-only.

Is there a way to set secret's tags from C# code?

I've found that it is possible from PowerShell (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/set-azkeyvaultsecret?view=azps-10.0.0), but I need to use C# code...

Thanks a lot in advance for any help.

Comment: `Tags` is readonly in terms you can not assign a new dictionary there. You can still modify the contents of the dictionary by setting its values

Comment: Thanks @bashis, somehow I didn't realize it at the first glance... Indeed, it is possible to add values and everything works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @bashis for his comment, it actually helped to figure out that there is no need to set `Tags` property. It is enough to add/update its values, as the following:

```
var client = new SecretClient(new Uri("keyVaultUri"), new DefaultAzureCredential());
            
var keyVaultSecret = new KeyVaultSecret(key, secret);

// here we modify tags property
keyVaultSecret.Properties.Tags.Add("SomeTagKey", "SomeTagValue");

await client.SetSecretAsync(keyVaultSecret);
```

Answer (score -2):

Unfortunately, the Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets library does not provide a built-in method to set tags for secrets directly. The `Tags` property is read-only as you mentioned.

However, you can achieve this using Azure Functions or Azure Logic Apps, which support creating and updating secrets with tags.

**Azure Functions**:
You can create an Azure Function with an HTTP trigger to create a secret and set its tags using the `CreateOrUpdateSecret` method. Here's a sample function in C#:

```cs
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

public static class KeyVaultFunction
{
    [FunctionName("CreateOrUpdateSecret")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        var secretName = req.Query["name"];
        var secretValue = req.Query["value"];
        var tags = req.Query["tags"].ToDictionary(x => x, x => x);

        var keyVaultUrl = "https://<your-keyvault-name>.vault.azure.net";
        var tokenProvider = new DefaultAzureCredential();
        var secretClient = new SecretClient(new Uri(keyVaultUrl), tokenProvider);

        var options = new SecretCreateOrUpdateOptions { Tags = tags };
        await secretClient.CreateOrUpdateSecretAsync(secretName, secretValue, options);

        return new OkObjectResult($"Secret {secretName} created or updated with tags.");
    }
}
```

**Azure Logic Apps**:
You can create an Azure Logic App with a "When an HTTP request is received" trigger to create a secret and set its tags. Here's a sample Logic App definition in JSON:

```cs
{
  "triggers": {
    "When_an_HTTP_request_is_received": {
      "inputs": {
        "schema": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "name",
            "value",
            "tags"
          }
        }
      },
      "kind": "Http",
      "type": "Request"
    }
  },
  "actions": {
    "Create_or_update_secret": {
      "inputs": {
        "host": {
          "connection": {
            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azure']['connectionId']"
          }
        },
        "method": "post",
        "path": "/<your-keyvault-name>/secrets",
        "queries": {
          "name": "@triggerBody()?['name']",
          "value": "@triggerBody()?['value']",
          "tags": "@triggerBody()?['tags']"
        },
        "headers": {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
      },
      "kind": "Http",
      "runAfter": {},
      "type": "Http"
    }
  }
}
```

Both approaches allow you to create or update a secret with tags using C# code or Azure Logic Apps. Keep in mind that you'll need to handle authentication and authorization for these approaches.

Comment: I do use Azure Function to call my service which should create secrets... I see `SecretCreateOrUpdateOptions` class in your code - where does this class reside? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: This is referenced in [a meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned/421848#comment961268_421848).